# We'd as well be 10 minutes back in time?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, grammaticality-in-context, poetry

In Storm by Tim Minchin, after a heavy argument, Tim says;

We'd as well be 10 minutes back in time,
For all the chance you'll change your mind.

Can you please explain that sentence to me from the grammatical point of view?

Comment: That you will change your mind is as unlikely as us time-traveling back in time 10 minutes.   We would just as likely be (*we would as well be*)  back in time ten minutes...

Comment: Or "We might as well go back in time ten minutes to the beginning of this argument for all the success (viz, none) we've had in changing your mind."

Comment: Yes, the upshot is "these past ten minutes have been an utter waste of time" with respect to getting you to change your mind.